# Are the boundary and initial conditions only effecting parameters make turbulence unpredictable?

Tags: fluid-dynamics, turbulence

The book that I used to study turbulence states that "*in a laboratory experiment initial and boundary conditions can not be fully under control, despite all the effort there will be inﬁnitesimal variations between experiments. Turbulence amplifies these variations and instantaneous velocity will differ from experiment to experiment.*" What I don't understand is the boundary and initial conditions are the only reason of unpredictability? If we consider ideal experiments that initial and boundary conditions exactly the same, can we say that the variation of instantaneous velocity in time at a specific location will be exactly the same for all experiments?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is just a long comment. The idealization must include instruments that have infinite precision, in a world without thermal fluctuations. In such case yes, if everything is exactly equal (including the position and velocity of every molecule) the predictions will be too. All these assuming a classical world, because quantum effects would make the same evolution impossible, even if you had the same initial and boundary conditions. 
Also  notice that in a chaotic system  the evolution is exponentially sensitive to initial conditions. So  the evolution of the different experiments will agree better at the beginning than at later times. However I do not think the level of precision to predict turbulence even for a few seconds might be reachable.

Comment: I had not anticipated that interactions at the molecular level would be effective. Navier-Stokes equations are based on Newton mechanics and since definition of same initial and boundary conditions won't be a problem for numerical simulations can we say that numerical approaches (like direct numerical solution technique) product same results for each solution?

Comment: I was talking of a laboratory experiment, of course in a Navier stokes simulation same conditions should result in same predictions. The problem I see is in the computer's truncation error, I am not an expert but I think it might be a problem even for simulations.

Comment: @Wolphramjonny Won't the truncation error be the same in every re-run of the simulation?

Comment: @sammygerbil yes, that makes sense, I didnt think about it